# Is there any way to get an XCode build setting to vary according to build ACTION (e.g. clean, rebuild)?

Tags: xcode, scons, xcodebuild

I'm trying to figure out exactly how `schemes` work in `xcode` and what they're for. I have a cross-platform product that's built on OS X using an external build system ( `scons` ). I'd like to be able to **build/debug** it from `Xcode`, mostly because of the symbol search and the debugger. I've been using `eclipse CDT` which mostly works well, but has some quirks.

I can mostly get this to work by creating an empty project and adding an **'external build system'** target. Then, as part of the **'Info'** of the target, I specify the **'Build Tool'** as **/usr/local/bin/scons**, and the **'Arguments'** are the build parameters that I send to scons. Basically I have the following build variables called `$(TARGET)` and `$(BUILD_TYPE)` that vary according to whether the build is debug or release, so those can be specified as conditional **'Build Settings'**.

The problem is I'd like `Menu->Project->Clean` to work. It looks like `Xcode/xcodebuilder` use the `$(ACTION)` variable to pass this on - where `$(ACTTION)` is either **'build'**, **'clean'**, or some other build actions. See [xcodebuild ACTION](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW45). Scons is a bit different - it has a built-in clean action that's invoked on the command line with `scons -c`. So my first thought was to use a conditional **'Build Setting'** to pass this parameter, but it turns out that conditional **'Build Settings'** don't seem to vary based on the build `ACTION` - just the build architecture and SDK.

Is it possible to add an expression to a **'Build Setting'** in `Xcode/xcodebuilder`? Is there another good way that I could get **'Clean'** to work in `Xcode` with scons?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: I really hate it when someone asks a question, "How do I use X?" on Stack Overflow, and someone else responds, "You don't want to use X.  Use Y."  It's just rude.

Comment: @Dietrich If the question is indeed, "how do I use X", the question should be closed. From what I am aware, Xcode doesn't support this. I'm suggesting to look at makefiles.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Questions about tools (compilers, IDEs) are appropriate on Stack Overflow.  Telling people that they should use different tools -- without justification -- is inappropriate behavior on this site.  Questions should not be closed just because the answer is "no".  Please familiarize yourself with the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Furthermore, the suggestion to use makefiles is patently absurd, if all you are doing with the makefile is calling SCons.

Answer (score 5):

Write a wrapper script for `SCons`, and put it in your project.  For example:

#### External Build Tool Configuration

- Build Tool: `$(PROJECT_DIR)/scons-xcode-wrapper.sh`
- Arguments: `$(ACTION)`

#### Wrapper Script

From an experiment, it looks like `$(ACTION)` is empty when building, and set to `clean` when cleaning.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$PROJECT_DIR"
case $1 in
  clean)
    scons -c
    ;;
  *)
    scons
    ;;
esac
```

Don't forget to `chmod +x` your script.

Answer (score 1):

With SCons, you can *programatically* set the build to perform a clean using the `SetOption()` function. The `clean` option and others that can be set are listed [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c2092.html#sect-command-line-option-strings).

The problem is that SCons treats command line options that arent in the form "--option" or "option=value" as targets. So its not possible to cause something like `scons clean` to perform a clean. I tested with the Alias() function and could not get it to work.

If you have the option to change the string that xcode uses for `$(ACTION)` to something like `clean=1` then you could something like the following to *programatically* do a clean:

```
env = Environment()

if ARGUMENTS.get('clean') == '1':
    print "Setting clean"
    env.SetOption('clean', True)

print env.GetOption('clean')
...
```

This will cause a clean:

```
scons clean=1
```

You could also consider the `AddOption()`, but this only allows for options with `--` prepended

Comment: Sadly I don't think that that's possible. You can definitely change the value of $(ACTION) - you just can't set it to vary with the build action. In other words, I could set ACTION to be clean=1, or -c for that matter, but then it would be clean=1 even for building. I was really hoping that I could define a 'Build Setting' in xcode using an expression - like creating a variable called CLEAN_VAR and setting it to a shell expression.

Answer (score 1):

Set your 'Arguments' parameter to end with:

```
--$(ACTION)
```

This will translate to:

```
scons [all your arguments] --clean
```

If you check the docs for scons [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.0.0/HTML/scons-user/c1965.html#sect-command-line-option-strings), you can see that `--clean` works just as well as `-c`

Clean is the only one that works however, the other build actions always come through blank.

Comment: Update for Xcode 7 - the other build actions no longer come through blank, making this more awkward than it once was

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the answers above, namely:

1. Set your arguments to something like `--xcode-action=$(ACTION)`.
2. Put code in your SConstruct like this:

   ```
   env.AddOption('--xcode-action',
                 dest='xcode_action',
                 type='string',
                 action='store',
                 default='',
                 help='The action Xcode wishes to perform')

   if GetOption('xcode_action') == 'clean':
       SetOption('clean', True)
   ```

This is basically the solution I'm using in [scons-xcode](https://bitbucket.org/al45tair/scons-xcode).